# Observed Object not updating in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

Attempting to update my main dashboard view once a user makes updates on their settings page. The issue is, the view does not update.

It updates correctly in the database and if I close the app out and reopen it displays the new data correctly. I would like the data to refresh live on the app when updated.  I figure I am **not** using StateObject and ObservedObject correctly.

If I can get some insight, help on the issue that'll be great. I think posting the entire code base would be redundant in solving the issue, for now I'll just post each view and how I'm passing data in between the views. I won't post my model class either, since I don't think the problem lies there (as I'm using an observableObject class with my var's all being Published.

Main View

```
struct UserDashboardView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = DashboardLogic ()
      var body: some View {
            TabView{
                UserDashController(vm: vm, signUpController: signUpController)
                        .tabItem{
                            VStack{
                                Image(systemName: "house.circle")
                                    .font(.title3)
                                Text("Home")
                            }
                        }
```

DashController (Where "Name" AND "bio" should be updated live when changed

```
struct UserDashController: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: DashboardLogic
   
    var body: some View {
        if !vm.isUserDataLoading { // << if user data loaded
            NavigationView{
                    HStack{
                        Text(vm.userModel?.name ?? "" ) // << what needs to change when udpated
                            .font(.title3)
                    }
                   
                    ProfileBio(userBio: vm.userModel?.userBio ?? "") //changes when updated
                        .padding(.top, -25)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $presentSettingsPage){
                PersonalSettingsView(vm: vm)  << where I update the data in this view
            }
          
        }
       
    } 
}
```

Settings View - where data is changed.

```
struct PersonalSettingsView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: DashboardLogic  //call to viewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
                    UpdatePersonalSettingsHStack(vm: vm, name: 
                        .constant(vm.userModel?.name ?? "Name not found"))
                    
                    HStack{
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.rectangle")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("ButtonTwo"))
                        TextField(vm.userModel?.userBio ?? "UserBio", text: $userBio).submitLabel(.done)
                            .onSubmit{
                                if (vm.userModel?.userBio != userBio){
                                    FirebaseManager.shared.firestore.collection("users").document(FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser!.uid).updateData(["userBio": userBio])
                                    showSuccessAlertForName.toggle()
                                    print("user Bio updated")
                                }
                            }
                            .alert(isPresented: $showSuccessAlertForName, content: {
                                Alert(title: Text("Bio Entered"),
                                       message: Text(""), dismissButton:
                                            .default(Text("Close")))
                            })
                            .padding(.trailing, 20)
                    }
```

Dashboard Logic

```
class DashboardLogic: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    @Published var userModel: UserModel?
    @Published var privateUserModel: privateUserModel?
 
    init(){
        self.fetchCurrentUser()
    }
   
    
    func fetchCurrentUser () {
        guard let uid = FirebaseManager.shared.auth.currentUser?.uid else {
            return
        }
     
        
        FirebaseManager.shared.firestore
            .collection("users").document(uid)
            .getDocument { snapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print ("failed to fetch user \(error)")
                    return
                }
            
            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "signedIn") // << update appStorage if no user
                print ("no data found for user")
                return
            }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.userModel = .init(data: data)
                    self.isUserDataLoading = false
                }
                
        }
       
    }
}
```

UserModel

```
struct UserModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
 
    var uid, name, gender, height, weight,userBio, agenda, profilePictureURL: String
    
    init(data: [String: Any]){
        self.uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
        self.name = data["name"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
        self.gender = data["gender"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
        self.height = data["height"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
        self.weight = data["weight"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
        self.userBio = data["userBio"] as? String ?? "No Bio entered"
        self.agenda = data["agenda"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
        self.profilePictureURL = data ["profilePicture"] as? String ?? "Unavailable"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show the code for `DashboardLogic`, but my suspicion is that you aren't using `@Published` properties on it. Also, keep in mind that nested `ObservableObject`s don't work out of the box, so if your userModel is an `ObservableObject` as well, you will have issues.

Comment: Got it - thank you. I added the dashboard logic in as well

Comment: Yeah — it was my second suspicion. You should not beat ObservableObjects. If you have to, you must manually link them with objectWillChange. But, again, try to avoid doing that — make your models structs.

Comment: Hmm okay okay noted, updated my UserModel (and the code snippet) to now be a struct. Should I be changing anything else ?

Comment: Hey jnpdx, your answer pointed me in the right direction. At first I was using objectWillChange and my model class wasn't updating. I realized I wasn't updating the class on the main thread. Once I put hte objectwillChange on the thread, i worked and my changes were updated live. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Use EnviornmentObject instead of using ObservedObject.

```
Add.envriornmentObject(YourViewModel())
```

Then use `@EnviornmentObject: YourViewModel`. This will solve the issue as all the views in the hierarchy will receive the data but make sure to add `.enviornmentObject(YourViewModel())` to the previews as they don't get the data.

Comment: The only safe way to initialized an `ObservableObject` in a `View` is using `@StateObject`